# Cropping two perpendicular curves at their intersections

Tags: mesh, edges, faces

[image: The selected curve and the unselected curve are perpendicular to each other. The selected curve passes through the unselected curve at arbitrary points.]

Hi,

I'd like to have about an efficient way of cropping the selected curve at every point where it intersects with the unselected curve (see picture).

Comment: Did you try the Boolean modifier?

Comment: Nope. How do I do that?

Comment: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDweCpDAB_o) should get you started. It will teach you the various ways you can use the modifier.

Comment: [Booleans seem to have enabled me to get the desired effect.](http://i.imgur.com/wz3ehVm.jpg?1) Thank you for your help! Is there any way in which I can mark your answer as having solved the problem?

Comment: I can post an answer for you, give me a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this result by using the *Boolean* modifier.

Select your large curved mesh, and add a *Boolean* modifier set to *Difference*.

[image: Add modifier]

This will make the curved wall follow the contours of the arch in the direction of the *Normals*. You may need to re-calculate them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) to get the desired result.

[image: Boolean Normals]

Now if you apply the modifier, you can remove the arch mesh and you should end up with a completed single mesh with the desired arch shape in it.

[image: Final mesh]